How equivalent of Windows' command > cmd /k
How equivalent of Windows' command
user> cmd /k "robocopy C:\x C:\y" /njh /njs /ndl

for cmder  command-line
which'd be launch cmd shell, and console/terminal at once only if not yet, then execute the following command (string) then stay on there
Help kindly
